# How can I paginate a document array in mongoose using aggregate?

Tags: database, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I want to paginate an array of documents called "Reviews" but I can't find a way to do it, since the code I execute paginate the documents for me and not the array of documents "Reviews".

> Code you tried to run

```
return await this.animeModel
  .aggregate()
  .match({ _id: Types.ObjectId(reviewPaginateData.animeId) })
  .unwind('$reviews')
  .group({
    _id: '$_id',
    reviews: { $push: '$reviews' },
  })
  .sort(reviewPaginateData.sort)
  .limit(reviewPaginateData.limit)
  .skip(reviewPaginateData.limit * reviewPaginateData.skip)
  .exec();
```

> Document structure

### [image: Document structure]

Any way to solve this problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with mongoose,  but I can write a shell query to perform the pagination on an array. So, that you can integrate it in mongoose.

The reason you are not able to paginate is that you are applying the `skip` and `limit` after `group` which is giving you an array as output. So, to apply pagination on the array itself you need to use `$slice` for more read [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match:{
      "_id":ObjectId("xyz")
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind:"$reviews"
  },
  {
    $group:{  
      "_id":"$_id",
      "reviews":{
        $push:"$reviews"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort:{
      sort_value:1
    }
  },
  {
    $project:{
      "reviews":{
        $slice:[
          "$reviews",
          skip_value,
          limit_value
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for the information and the code, it works perfectly for me. <3

Comment: I am glad it helped :)